# Display Data from access DB to Datagirdview fix

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, datagridview

hello Guys i have problem in my good its work good but all time get same Data not clean 
my problem is when i add rate first time i get display data good but when i add another rate when i not close form i get display data double time like 54  and 54 too so how i can clear datagridview before display another data

```
Conn.Open()

DataBindings.Clear()

da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT [ID], [Rate], [DateTime], [NameDriver1] from Assess", Conn)

'  from Assess", Conn)

da.Fill(DataSetClient, "Assess")



Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))


source1.DataSource = view1

DataGridAssess.DataSource = view1
DataGridAssess.Refresh()

DataGridAssess.Sort(DataGridAssess.Columns("ID"), System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)


Conn.Close()

' code for name columns 
'  DataGridAssess.Columns(0).Visible = False
DataGridAssess.Columns(0).HeaderText = "ID"
DataGridAssess.Columns(1).HeaderText = "Rate"
DataGridAssess.Columns(2).HeaderText = "Data Rate"
DataGridAssess.Columns(3).HeaderText = "Name Driver"
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand, but the SQL is selecting all the rows so that is what will show.

Comment: i know my sql  will show all data but my problem was when show data show double data and if i add more rate it show more data double so i fix it to clean datasetclient= dataset and my problem is fixed

Answer (score -1):

oh now i fix my problem only can add this code after  this

```
DataBindings.Clear()

DataSetClient.Clear()
```

so i fix my problem by this code `DataSetClient.Clear()` 
thanx